# CentOS 7 KDM Plasma + Hyper-v + WiFi - no connection

Tags: wireless-networking, centos, hyper-v, hypervisor

First, I will state I am a newbie to linux.  I have installed the CentOS KDM Plasma with a ton of the available bells and whistles so-to-speak.  I want to be able to work remotely on a WiFi connection (home  for the most part) so I followed the instructions from this old posting on SuperUser:

[Connecting a Hyper-V VM (Linux based) to the internet via wifi - No wifi appears to connect to in Linux](https://superuser.com/questions/696717/connecting-a-hyper-v-vm-linux-based-to-the-internet-via-wifi-no-wifi-appears)

I think my problem is that the Hypervisor isn't working with the WiFi but I don't know if it is that it cannot use WiFi or if I don't have it configured correctly.  I am going to post on here and find a CentOS forum also.  I would also appreciate it if anyone could point me in the directions of some good reading material on CentOS 7 KDM Plasma to help me get comfortable with it and find things on it.  I was on a different version when I went to school but I wanted to find a more recent/current distro and found the 7.

I am including screenshots of network adaptor and vm switch settings:

[W10 Pro - Network Adaptors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/22BFg.jpg)
[W10 Pro - WiFi Adaptor Bridge Internal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j3KWb.jpg)
[W10 Pro - WiFi Adaptor Bridge External](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tzue7.jpg)
[VM Virtual Switch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5L9uZ.jpg)
[Hypervisor Virtual Switch Internal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sasmx.jpg)
[Hypervisor Virtual Switch External](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oqu7p.jpg)

Thanks for all the help.

Sincerely,

Wonder Woman

Comment: Your linux VM will never see a Wifi NIC...it's never passed through.  You can just use the virtual NIC provided by Hyper-V.  You'll connect to your Wifi on the host Windows, then LInux will piggyback on it and use the wifi connection...it will appear as a LAN connection in Linux.